# BlackBerry Widgets in the wild?

Tags: blackberry, widget, blackberry-widgets

I've been writing BlackBerry applications in Java and I'm interesting in developing widgets as well, but I'd like to have a look at a real world BlackBerry application implemented using the Widget API first. I find a lot of tutorials, code snippets and forum threads / stackoverflow questions regarding BlackBerry widgets, however I wasn't able to find a live widget that I can run on my BlackBerry (or maybe I just didn't realize it was a widget).

So, are there any (free) real world BlackBerry widgets I can try to learn the look and feel of BlackBerry widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally stumbled over a small list of applications implemented as widgets:

http://www.blackberrycool.com/2010/08/17/examples-of-blackberry-widgets-in-app-world/